# PostgreSQL 9.3: Migrate text column to macaddr type

Tags: postgresql, mac-address

I have a table with a **text column representing a MAC address**, but I want to **use the macaddr type instead**. So, I tried:

```
alter table mytable alter column mac_column type macaddr;
```

And got this error

```
ERROR:  column "mac_column" cannot be cast automatically to type macaddr
HINT:  Specify a USING expression to perform the conversion.
```

But I don't know what to use as USING expression:

```
alter table mytable alter column mac_column type macaddr using(????????)
```

**What should I use as USING expression?**

Many thanks in advance

Comment: be careful with the `macaddr` data type, it does not support 8-byte MAC addresses (EUI-64)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can’t simply change the data type because data is already there in the column. Since the data is of type `String` PostgreSQL can't expect it as macaddr though you entered valid String representation of the `macaddr`. So now, as PostgreSQL suggested you can use the ‘USING’ expression to cast your data into `macaddr`.

```
ALTER TABLE mytable ALTER COLUMN mac_column TYPE macaddr USING(mac_column::macaddr)
```

Comment: Yes, I have valid MAC address representation on that column. So, this is just what I was looking for. Many thanks!

Comment: `SELECT 'ncjdfbj'::string;
ERROR:  type "string" does not exist
`